# Portable way of accessing an array of bool (C++11) from Nvidia PTX

Tags: c++, c++11, boolean, gpu, ptx

I need to do GPU computations on an boolean array `bool[]` (note, not a `std::vector<bool>`) which was created in CPU memory (with C++11 code) and then copied to the GPU via `cuMemCpy` or similar.

First question:

`sizeof(bool)` reports 1 byte. Is this guaranteed by the C++11 standard?

Second question:

Is `true` (`false`) always represented as `1` (`0`) (in the `unsigned char` representation) or does the compiler have freedom here ? (It could use any non-zero integer less than 256 if it wanted)

Third question (PTX specific):

In PTX logical operations `or`, `xor`, etc. only operate on types larger than 8 bit. That is I can do logical operations on an `unsigned int` with `or.u32 <out>,<in1>,<in2>`. However since C++11 `bool` type seems to be 8 bits does this mean I can not operate on an array of `bools` that was copied directly from CPU to GPU memory and thus do I need to convert the array of `bools` first into some type PTX logical operations can operate on, i.e. `u32`, `u16`, etc.?

Comment: Whereas `true` is guaranteed to **convert** to `1` (and likewise `false` to `0`) when **converting** from `bool` to an integer type, the actual representation is completely up to the implementation, both regarding the size as well as the bits used for `true` and `false`. So unfornutely the answer to the first two questions is that nothing the like is guaranteed by standard, even if in practice usually behaving exactly like you assumed.

Comment: You understand that the limitation you are describing in the last question are because the register size is always 32 bits? You are free to load an 8 bit type into the lower bits of a 32 bit register and perform logical operations on it as you see fit. But on a bool, you only have 1 bit anyway. Are you sure this is really the way you would want to do this?

Comment: There are other register sizes than 32bit. PTX allows logical operations on `u16` and `u64` for example. To address your question: Yes, I have to do logical computation on the GPU. I see 2 ways: Convert data in CPU memory to something PTX can handle - or - leave the data format, load 8bits (`ld.u8`) and convert to larger type, i.e. `cvt.u32.u8`. However I worry about portability

Comment: @Frank I think *talonmies*'s last sentence (forgive any possible misunderstanding) was more on the lines of thinking about using some more abstract representation of a boolean array, like an array of `uint32`s with the individual **bits** representing the actual boolean values, whose 16/32 : 1 data and computation reduction might really pay the additional abstraction overhead, especially for large boolean arrays. But it depends on what else you're doing with this array apart from mere logicals over the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

**First answer:**

No, this is not guaranteed. See `[expr.sizeof]/1`, and the associated footnote:

> ... sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1. The result of sizeof applied to any other fundamental type (3.9.1) is implementation-defined. [Note: in particular, sizeof(bool), sizeof(char16_t), sizeof(char32_t), and sizeof(wchar_t) are implementation-defined<sup>75</sup>. ...
>
> 75) sizeof(bool) is not required to be 1.

---

**Second Answer:**

I'm pretty sure that the value representation for `bool` objects is implementation defined, but I can't find anything explicitly stating that. The closest that I can get is `[basic.types]/4`:

> ... For trivially copyable types, the value representation is a set of bits in the object representation that determines a value, which is one discrete element of an implementation-defined set of values.

---

**Third Answer:**

I don't know, but from your description, it certainly looks like you would have to change the types.